# Serve a csv file?

Tags: files

I have a Drupal 7 site. After some form actions, I want the user to be able to click on a link to download a csv file of the results, but I don't need the csv hanging around the site forever. I have the file being written to the temporary file system using the `temporary://` streamwrapper.

Is there functionality in core that can offer this file for download? If so, what is it? Or else, do I need to/can I write a menu callback function that sets the mime header and all that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I did it. I saved a file using `file_unmanaged_save_data()`

```
$file = file_unmanaged_save_data($csv, "temporary://" . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
```

Then I made a menu callback that was just `MENU_CALLBACK`, which calls this:

```
function download_file($filename) {
  $filename = t($filename);
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-type', 'application/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=\'output.csv\'');
  echo file_get_contents('temporary://' . $filename);
}
```

I should add an additional check to make sure that the file exists before echoing its contents.

Comment: Drupal has a function for this, you don't need to roll your own. Ref [file_transfer()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_transfer/7)

Answer (score 3):

The [project Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) has a [File Example module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/file_example--file_example.module/7) demonstrating the Drupal File API (and Stream Wrappers).